# scanf issue multiple input

Tags: c, struct, int, scanf

Whenever I attempt to scan in my input, example: `JASON BOURNE JULY 5 1972`, the program crashes.

```
scanf("%s %s %s %d %d", temp->fname, temp->lname, temp->month, temp->day, temp->year);
```

I determined it has to do with the `%d`'s whereas if I put:

```
scanf("%s %s %s", temp->fname, temp->lname, temp->month);
scanf("%d %d", temp->month, temp->day);
```

The `String` values are correct and the program crashed before `int`'s could be assigned.

Here's a copy of my struct:

```
typedef struct node{
    char fname [29];
    char lname [29];

    char month [9];
    int day;
    int year;

    struct student * next;
    struct student * previous;
} student;
```

and here is a copy of my function in main():

```
    student * head = malloc(sizeof(student));
    student * temp = head;
    int num = numStudents;
    while(num != 0){
        scanf("%s %s %s %d %d", temp->fname, temp->lname, temp->month, temp->day, temp->year);
        printf("FUNCTION NEVER REACHES THIS POINT");
        temp = temp->next = malloc(sizeof(student));
        num--;
    }temp->next = NULL;
```

Comment: What type of argument does `scanf` expect with `%d`?

Comment: Use & with variables for ℅d specifier.

Comment: scanf should expect an integer value, and adding & does not fix my issue

Comment: @KyleBatchelor No, it shouldn't. Why do you think it should expect an integer?

Comment: If everyone used `gcc -Wall -Werror`, 50% of Stack Overflow questions tagged `c` would never have to be asked. *"scanf should expect an integer value"* is completely wrong. How does `scanf` assign a value when e.g. `4` is passed to it?

Comment: @KyleBatchelor seeing as you didn't post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, it's anyone's guess whether there are other problems than the incorrect use of `scanf`.

Comment: The issue of whether `temp = temp->next = ...` invokes UB might be interesting. I think it doesn't, but I'm not a real language lawyer.

Comment: Am I incorrectly using scanf? My input is in the form: firstname lastname month day year (string string string int int)

Comment: @KyleBatchelor You haven't answered my question. Why do you think it should expect an integer?

Comment: @WeatherVane my function never reaches that point because of the issue with scanf not assigning the int variables and crashing my program.

Comment: @Melpomene, because my input is restricted to only the format: string string string int int

Comment: @KyleBatchelor I'm not talking about your input. I'm talking about the arguments you're passing to `scanf`.

Comment: @melpomene My arguments, I believe, are pointing to the `int` values within my temporary struct

Comment: Your arguments are not *pointing* at all. The `temp` is, but to values, not pointers.

Comment: @KyleBatchelor Why are you avoiding my question? **Why do you think `scanf` should expect an integer argument for `%d` in the format string?**

Comment: @melpomene, maybe I'm not understanding your question, I'm using command line to run my program via the command `programname.exe < input.in`. where the input file is `input.in` which contains data in the form `JASON BOURNE JULY 5 1972`. I think scanf should expect an integer argument from %d because on this line the 4th and 5th items are integers.

Comment: @KyleBatchelor You have a type error in your code. It does not matter how you run it or what the input is. You're calling `scanf` with arguments that have the wrong type, and I have no idea why and you're apparently unable to explain.

Comment: This is torture. Please read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx). There is an example of how you pass arguments to `scanf` for a variety of variable types, including `int`.

Comment: Note that `JULIAN NAVARRES SEPTEMBER 19 1980' won't work reliably because `SEPTEMBER` is too long to fit into `temp->month` (it needs 9 characters plus a null byte to terminate the string — 10 bytes in total).

Comment: And `if (scanf("%s %s %s %d %d", temp->fname, temp->lname, temp->month, &temp->day, &temp->year) != 5) { …report error and abandon loop… }`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136686/discussion-on-question-by-kyle-batchelor-scanf-issue-multiple-input).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get everything to work if anyone is interested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//Struct for Student
struct student{
    char fname [29];
    char lname [29];

    char month [9];
    int day;
    int year;

    struct student *next;
    struct student *previous;
};

//Pre-Call
void printList(struct student *node);
struct student * insertNode(struct student * list, char fname[29], char lname[29], char month[9], int day, int year);


//Main function
int main(){
    //Take Input and Assign Variables
    int classes, i;
    scanf("%d", &classes);

    for(i = 0; i < classes; i++){
        int numStudents, j;
        scanf("%d", &numStudents);

        struct student *list = NULL; //Create LL
        int num = numStudents, day, year;
        char fname[29]; char lname[29]; char month[9];
        //Assign Values
        while(num != 0){
            scanf("%s %s %s %d %d", &fname, &lname, &month, &day, &year);
            list = insertNode(list, fname, lname, month, day, year);
            num--;
        }

        //

        printList(list);
    }


    return 0;
}


//Function to insert a node to the LL
struct student * insertNode(struct student * list, char fname[29], char lname[29], char month[9], int day, int year){
    //If the list is empty
    if(list == NULL){
        struct student * tempNode = (struct student *) malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        strcpy(tempNode->fname,fname);
        strcpy(tempNode->lname,lname);
        strcpy(tempNode->month,month);
        tempNode->day = day;
        tempNode->year = year;
        tempNode->next = NULL; // Extremely Important
        return tempNode;
    }
    //If the list has a node
    list->next = insertNode(list->next, fname, lname, month, day, year);
    return list;
}


//Function to print a LL
void printList(struct student * node){
    if(node->next == NULL)
        printf("%s %s %s %d %d\n", node->fname, node->lname, node->month, node->day, node->year);
    else
    {
        printf("%s %s %s %d %d\n", node->fname, node->lname, node->month, node->day, node->year);
        printList(node->next);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf()` before calling `insertNode()`; you do not want to insert an incomplete mish-mash of data from a new line and an old, or repeat the previous entry on encountering EOF.  Always check input functions — they fail (routinely), and encounter EOF (routinely).  Even though it seems a complete pain, do it — it is necessary.